# Gutenberg: Issue trying to commit locally

Tags: block-editor, accessibility

I am working on a small accessibility [bug](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/41500) for Gutenberg, but cannot commit because of the following errors that seem to do with linting. I have tried deleting node-modules, package-lock, and re-cloning in a different install, and I'm not getting anywhere. Deving inside Local. Running `npm run test` passes.

MacOS Monterey 12.6
M1
node: 14.20.1
npm: 6.14.17

```
% git commit -m "Add scrollable and focusable container"
  ✔ Preparing...
  ❯ Running tasks...
    ❯ Running tasks for *.{js,json,ts,tsx,yml,yaml}
      ✖ wp-scripts format
    ❯ Running tasks for *.{js,ts,tsx}
      ✖ wp-scripts lint-js
    ❯ Running tasks for *.scss
      ✖ wp-scripts lint-style
    ↓ Running tasks for package-lock.json [skipped]
      → No staged files match package-lock.json
    ↓ Running tasks for packages/*/package.json [skipped]
      → No staged files match packages/*/package.json
    ↓ Running tasks for {docs/{toc.json,tool/*.js},packages/{*/README.md,components/src/*/**/README.md}} [skipped]
      → No staged files match {docs/{toc.json,tool/*.js},packages/{*/README.md,components/src/*/**/README.md}}
    ✔ Running tasks for packages/**/*.{js,ts,tsx,json}
  ↓ Applying modifications... [skipped]
    → Skipped because of errors from tasks.
  ✔ Reverting to original state...
  ✔ Cleaning up...



✖ wp-scripts format found some errors. Please fix them and try committing again.

[error] No files matching the pattern were found: "/Users/myuser/Local".
[error] No files matching the pattern were found: "Sites/gbdev/app/public/wp-content/plugins/gutenberg/packages/components/src/modal/index.tsx".



✖ wp-scripts lint-style found some errors. Please fix them and try committing again.

Error: No files matching the pattern "/Users/myuser/Local, Sites/gbdev/app/public/wp-content/plugins/gutenberg/packages/components/src/modal/style.scss" were found.
  at standalone (/Users/myuser/Local Sites/gbdev/app/public/wp-content/plugins/gutenberg/node_modules/stylelint/lib/standalone.js:266:43)
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)



✖ wp-scripts lint-js found some errors. Please fix them and try committing again.
  
  
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 8.3.0

No files matching the pattern "/Users/myuser/Local" were found.
Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

Any help would be appreciated, I am sure it is something small I am missing

Comment: Could it be that you've capitalized some letters in your uri?

Comment: Thanks for the reply rudtek. This is in the Gutenberg Plugin, I am updating the [modal](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/components/src/modal/index.tsx) tsx file to include a new <div> around the children, so I do not believe the uri is an issue